# Como controlar declarar múltiples GPIO como pwm en php (Raspberry pi)

Tags: php, apache

¿Alguien sabe si se puede, y como se puede declarar más de un GPIO de la `raspberry pi` como salida pwm con un archivo `php`?, he logrado hacerlo, pero solo con el GPIO 18, ¿saben si hay alguna librería aparte de la que estoy usando (wiringPi) que te permita usar más de un GPIO como salida pwm?

El programa se ejecuta a través de un archivo `html` en apache.

Answer (score 0):

según mi búsqueda rápida por internet al parecer la raspberry solo tiene el gpio18 como PWM, te adjunto la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola bienvenido! no te olvides por favor de mirar el [tour] y tambien [answer]. Gracias por el aporte!